# Simulate div click multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got slider in template glitching, and code is minimized. So, got tired of looking for the cause of the problem and decided to use a quick hack.

I need to fire a div click multiple times.
I've used this piece of code to trigger a click

```
$('.control-prev').trigger('click');
```

Works fine for one time click.
Now, how do i make it click multiple times?

Comment: call it multiple times... ie use a loop.. `for(var i = 0; i<10;i++){ $('.control-prev').trigger('click');}`

Comment: "*…and code is minimized*" - but, of course, you kept a back-up copy of the un-minified code, to deal with issues like this, right?

Comment: Hm. It still triggered only one click. p.s. unfortunately i didn't get the un-minified code in the beginning, and cant get a hold of developer who has built the template now...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/br4Lmyso/ (*warning: creates three alerts, just to quickly show it works*)

```
// set your count to whatever you want. Get a reference to the div 
// so you're not querying the DOM everytime.
var triggerCount = 3;
var triggerDiv = $('.control-prev');

// loop!
for(var i = 0; i < triggerCount; i++) {

     triggerDiv.trigger('click');

}
```

Comment: still only one click simulated

Comment: Works fine in the JSFiddle I posted above. You must have other issues going on with your code. Any error messages in the console?

Comment: GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED   and four more of that kind, just with a different source of the cast_sender.js

Comment: Does it work for you in the JSFiddle I posted? You may want to try to add some console.log() events within the callback function after the click, to be 100% its not firing.

Comment: Yeah. It does work in jsfiddle.  The problem i've got is that slider's next button doesn't work until previous bttn is clicked (which throws everything to the last item). So, i thought i'd hack it with auto click on "previous" button and scrolling it all the way back to the first slider item (purpose of multiple clicks). I've also tried inserting the alert code to see if it really does trigger multiple clicks, and alerts just wouldn't stop at all.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, `trigger(...)` does not simulate the click behavior and there is no way you can simulate the click behavior. What it does is to call the function that handle given event. These two are total different. For example:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
});

$('#test').dblclick(function() {
    console.log("Double Click");
});

$('#test').trigger('click');
$('#test').trigger('click');
```

Despite of rapidly trigger two clicks, the double click will not trigger.

Comment: Well, no; but if you want to trigger a double-click, you'd use: `.trigger('dblclick');`

Comment: @DavidThomas you don't get my point. My point is that trigger('click') does not exactly the same as have your mouse click on it. The OP want to simulate the click because we want to work with minimized code. The code work when he use browser and do several clicks and he want to generate the same effect by using code to trigger several clicks. However, they are two different thing.